# I want to know the points of a vector when I know one of the points and also the distance between the two.

Tags: vectors, pythagorean-triples

So I have a vector equation which is

$$(1,2,-1) + t(2,1,-2)$$

I also know a point of that line which is

$$(0,0,1)$$

I need to know all the points in which the distance is 3 from the point at (0,0,1)

Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that (0,0,1) is actually ON the line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit unclear, but I think you are looking for the values of $t$ such that the distance from (0,0,1) to (1,2,-1)+t(2,1,-2) is 3.  The Euclidean distance between the point and a parameterized point on the line can be written as 
$$
\sqrt{(1+2t-0)^2+(2+1t-0)^2+(-1-2t-1)^2}
$$
so you are looking for $t$ such that 
$$
\sqrt{(1+2t)^2+(2+t)^2+(-2-2t)^2}=3
$$

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. I don't why I didn't think of it myself. Thank you very much.